# ¿Alguien sabe que podria hacer para hacer funcionar mi log in y registro con conexion a base de datos mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, xampp

He intentado borrando el ($query) del **`$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);`**
Pero en verdad no entiendo cual podría ser el problema y el como podría solucionarlo porque en si no recuerdo como lo programe por que copie el código de un proyecto que realice como proyecto final el año pasado.

---

#### Como funciona :

***1.-*** Se supone que al ingresar a la pagina llenas iniciar sesion si esque tienes tus datos registrados en la pagina y sino este te manda un aviso de datos no existentes.

***2.-*** Si te quieres registrar solo le das al link y te lleva al apartado de registro y al capturar los datos te aparece un aviso de datos registrados y se guardan en la base de datos.

el registro y el ***login*** se activan y diferencian mediante ***los botones btningresar "ingresar"*** y ***btnregistrar "registrar"***

---

Cada vez que intento ***registrar los datos*** y ***iniciar sesion*** me aparece este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PW__PIA\InfoGames\log in2\login2_registrar.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PW__PIA\InfoGames\log in2\login2_registrar.php(14): mysqli_num_rows(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PW__PIA\InfoGames\log in2\login2_registrar.php on line 14

**Este es el codigo y formulario original que funciona bien sin errores:**------------------------
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?php

//CODIGO ORIGINAL SIN ERRORES (FUNCIONA BIEN)

include("conexion.php");

$nombre = $_POST["usuario"];
$pass   = $_POST["pass"];

//Login
if(isset($_POST["btningresar"]))
{
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = '$nombre' AND password='$pass'");
    $nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
    if($nr==1)
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Bienvenido $nombre'); window.location= ../inicio/inicio.html </script>";
        header("Location: ../inicio/inicio.html");
    }else
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Usuario no existe'); window.location='log in.html' </script>";
        
    }
}

//Registrar
if(isset($_POST["btnregistrar"]))
{
    $sqlgrabar = "INSERT INTO login(usuario,password) values ('$nombre','$pass')";
    
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlgrabar))
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Usuario registrado con exito: $nombre'); window.location='log in.html' </script>";
    }else 
    {
        echo "Error: ".$sqlgrabar."<br>".mysql_error($conn);
    }
}


?>
```

**Este es el codigo y formulario ya con el codigo cambiado y el que me da errores:**--------------

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../log in2/login2_css.css">
    <title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="bienvenido">
        <h1 class="h1_al">InfoGames</h1>
        <hr>
       <p class="pp">Bienvenidos a nuestra pagina web  <br><br>
         Nota: Esta pagina no es oficial y solo es un proyecto para la materia de POO y TPOO de la facultad de FIME de la UANL</p>
        
         <br>

         <img src="../img/fime.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px; margin-left: 30px;" >
         <img src="../img/uanl.png" style="width: 130px; height: 130px; margin-left: 30px;">
        </div>

    <div class="formulario">
        <form action="login2_registrar.php" method="POST">

            <h1 class="h1_al">Inicia sesion</h1>


            <div class="caja1">

                <div class="nombre">
                
                    <p class="p2">Nombre:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre" required> <br>
        
                </div>
                
                <div class="apellido">
                
                    <p class="p2">Apellido:</p>
                    <input type="ap" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required> <br>
        
                </div>


            </div>
            
            <p>Correo:</p>
            <input type="co" name="correo" placeholder="Correo" required> <br>
          


            <p>Contraseña:</p>
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" required> <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" name="btningresar">

            <p class="registro">¿No tienes cuenta? <br>
                <a href="../log in2/registro_us.html">Registrate</a>
            </p>

        </form>
    </div>
    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```html
<?php

//CODIGO CAMBIADO PERO CON ERRORES A PARTIR DE LA LINEA 14 EN 
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);

include("conexion2.php");

$nombre = $_POST["usuario"];
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$pass   = $_POST["pass"];

//Login
if(isset($_POST["btningresar"]))
{
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario ='$nombre' AND apellido ='$apellido' AND correo ='$correo' AND password='$pass'");
    $nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
    if($nr==1)
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Bienvenido $nombre'); window.location= ../inicio/Inicio.html </script>";
        header("Location: ../inicio/Inicio.html");
    }else
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Usuario no existe'); window.location='../log in2/log in2.html' </script>";
        
    }
}

//Registrar
if(isset($_POST["btnregistrar"]))
{
    $sqlgrabar = "INSERT INTO login(usuario,apellido,correo,password) values ('$nombre','$apellido','$correo','$pass')";
    
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlgrabar))
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Usuario registrado con exito: $nombre'); window.location='../log in2/log in2.html' </script>";
    }else 
    {
        echo "Error: ".$sqlgrabar."<br>".mysql_error($conn);
    }
}


?>
```

---

**Este es el codigo del comentario de @A. Cedano**---------------------

```html
<?php
$nombre = $_POST["usuario"] ?? null;
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"] ?? null;
$correo = $_POST["correo"] ?? null;
$pass   = $_POST["pass"] ?? null;

if ($nombre && $apellido && $correo && $pass) 
{
    include("conexion2.php");
    if ($conn)
    {
        //Login
        if(isset($_POST["btningresar"]))
        {        
            $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login_poo WHERE usuario ='$nombre' AND apellido ='$apellido' AND correo ='$correo' AND password='$pass'";
            if ( $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ) 
            {
                $nr = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
                if($nr[0] > 0) 
                {
                    $msg="Bienvenido $nombre";
                    $url="../inicio/Inicio.html";
                }else 
                {
                    $msg="Usuario no existe";
                    $url="../log in2/log in2.html";
                }
            }else 
            {
                $msg=sprintf( "Error: %s",mysqli_error($conn) );
                $url="../log in2/error.html";
                #Define $url para este caso
            }
        }

        //Registrar
        elseif(isset($_POST["btnregistrar"]))
        {
            $sql= "INSERT INTO login_poo (usuario,apellido,correo,password) values ('$nombre','$apellido','$correo','$pass')";
            if( $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) )
            {
                if( mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) {
                    $msg="Usuario registrado con exito: $nombre";
                    $url="../log in2/log in2.html";            
                }
                else 
                {
                    $msg="Usurio no registrado: clave duplicada u otro motivo";
                    $url="../log in2/registro_us.html";
                    # Define $url para este caso
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                $msg=sprintf( "Error: %s",mysqli_error($conn) );
                $url="../log in2/log in2.html";
                # Define $url para este caso
            }
        
      }
      else 
      {
        $msg="Ni btningresar ni btnregistrar fueron presionados";
        $url="../log in2/registro_us.html";
        #Define $url para este caso
      }  
  }
  else 
  {
      $msg="Conexión errónea";
      $url="../log in2/error.html";
      #Define $url para este caso
  }
}
else 
{
    $msg="Faltan datos en el post";
    $url="../log in2/log in2.html";
    #Define $url para este caso
}
/*
echo "<script> alert($msg); window.location=$url</script>";
header("Location: $url");
*/
var_dump($msg);
var_dump($conn)

          
?>
```

---

**ARCHIVO DE CONEXION**----------------------------------------------

```html
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "******";
$dbname = "******";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

if(!$conn)
{
    die("No hay conexion:" .mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

> string(49) "Error: Unknown column 'usuario' in 'where clause'" object(mysqli)#1 (18) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["client_info"]=> string(14) "mysqlnd 8.0.11" ["client_version"]=> int(80011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(1054) ["error"]=> string(42) "Unknown column 'usuario' in 'where clause'" ["error_list"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["errno"]=> int(1054) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "42S22" ["error"]=> string(42) "Unknown column 'usuario' in 'where clause'" } } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(21) "5.5.5-10.4.21-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(100421) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "42S22" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(69) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Por favor, incluye el código a texto usando snippets. Las fotos tienen pésima calidad e impiden reproducir tu problema a quien intente ayudarte..

Comment: Listo, disculpa no haberlo incluido la verdad no sabia como agregarlo es mi primera pregunta

Comment: @Emmanuel no pasa nada demasiado bien esta tu pregunta para ser la primera vez y por favor acepta mi edición para una mayor calidad

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1
> ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given

Indica que la función espera un objeto del tipo `mysqli_result`, pero que en cambio está recibiendo un booleano.

¿Por qué ocurre eso? Porque la consulta falló debido a algún motivo, y el resultado de `query()` en ese caso es un valor `false`.

Vamos a implementar un código en el cual sean controlados todos los posibles errores (yo llamo a eso *programación pesimista*). Es decir, tú no puedes programar pensando que el mundo es color de rosa (*programación optimista*), tu tarea como programador es prever todo aquello que pueda salir mal, para capturar esos errores y actuar en consecuencia.

Vamos a ello:

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST["usuario"] ?? null;
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"] ?? null;
$correo = $_POST["correo"] ?? null;
$pass   = $_POST["pass"] ?? null;

if ($nombre && $apellido && $correo && $pass) 
{
    include("conexion2.php");
    if ($conn)
    {
        //Login
        if(isset($_POST["btningresar"]))
        {        
            $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE usuario ='$nombre' AND apellido ='$apellido' AND correo ='$correo' AND password='$pass'";
            if ( $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ) 
            {
                $nr = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
                if($nr[0] > 0) 
                {
                    $msg="Bienvenido $nombre";
                    $url="../inicio/Inicio.html";
                }else 
                {
                    $msg="Usuario no existe";
                    $url="../log in2/log in2.html";
                }
            }else 
            {
                $msg=sprintf( "Error: %s",mysqli_error($conn) );
                #Define $url para este caso
            }
        }

        //Registrar
        elseif(isset($_POST["btnregistrar"]))
        {
            $sql= "INSERT INTO login(usuario,apellido,correo,password) values ('$nombre','$apellido','$correo','$pass')";
            if( $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) )
            {
                if( mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) {
                    $msg="Usuario registrado con exito: $nombre";
                    $url="../log in2/log in2.html";            
                }else 
                {
                    $msg="Usurio no registrado: clave duplicada u otro motivo";
                    # Define $url para este caso
                }
            }else 
            {
                $msg=sprintf( "Error: %s",mysqli_error($conn) );
                # Define $url para este caso
            }
        
      }else {
        $msg="Ni btningresar ni btnregistrar fueron presionados";
        #Define $url para este caso
      }  
  }else 
  {
      $msg="Conexión errónea";
      #Define $url para este caso
  }
}else 
{
    $msg="Faltan datos en el post";
    #Define $url para este caso
}
echo "<script> alert($msg); window.location=$url</script>";
header("Location: $url");
exit();             
?>
```

#### Observaciones importantes sobre este código

- Como ya se dijo más arriba, se implementa un estilo de programación en el cual son controlados todos los eventuales errores.
- Se van evaluando las variables y objetos según su orden de uso. Por ejemplo, parece que para este contexto, la existencia de las variables pasadas en el POST son **esenciales**, por eso es **lo primero que se evalúa de una forma global**. Si alguna de esas variables está vacía, el código irá el mensaje de que no hay datos en el POST. En segundo lugar, se verifica que la conexión no sea nula, y así sucesivamente. Es importante entender esto, si quieres escribir un código claro y coherente.
- El estilo de programación que he seguido es el siguiente: definir en todos los casos una variable `$msg` que será lo que aparezca en el `alert` y una variable `$url` que será la dirección a la que se dirigirá el programa en todos los casos. Simplemente para que veas **las lagunas** a las que conduce la *programación optimista*, en tu código original hay al menos cinco casos en los que el programa no sabrá para donde ir. En la respuesta te he puesto una nota que dice: `#Define $url para este caso`. En todos esos casos, tú debes definir una URL para redigir el programa. Dado que no sé a dónde debe ir en esos casos, lo he dejado a tu arbitrio. Pero es algo que debes hacer sí o sí para que el programa quede completo.
- En consonancia con lo dicho anteriormente, verás que el programa muestra el alert y redigire **una sola vez**, al final del mismo. Por eso te decía que en todos los casos debería haber una variable `$url` definida, pues el programa debería ir a alguna parte en caso de error.
- Para los casos de error de `mysqli` tú estabas usando la función antigua: `mysql_error`, considera que todas las funciones `mysql_` (sin la `i`) provocarán un error falta desde PHP 7, porque ya no existen en el núcleo del programa.
- Por último, aparecen dos redirecciones en tu código, una desde Javascript y otra desde PHP. Deberías dejar una sola redirección, no dos, y decidirte por un estilo. No es bueno mezclar contextos: cliente (Javascript) y servidor (PHP). De hecho, hoy día tú puedes interactuar de una forma más elegante, más limpia y más transparente entre cliente y servidor usando herramientas como Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.

Espero haber sido claro, si no entiendes algo, dilo en comentarios. He optimizado otras cosas, como es, asegurarte de que realmente hubo una inserción (eso se hace contando las filas afectadas, no verificando si la query fue exitosa). Y también he usado una consulta del tipo `SELECT COUNT(*)` porque es la forma más segura y eficaz de saber si un registro existe. `num_rows` no siempre es seguro, porque depende de la configuración del buffer.

Lo olvidaba: **como nota de seguridad**, tus consultas son altamente vulnerables a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Deberías implementar **consultas preparadas** para prevenir ese gravísimo riesgo.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135798/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-alguien-sabe-que-podria-hacer-para-hacer-func).